How to disable URI encoding in Ktor Client?
I am using Ktor Client in Kotlin multiplatform app. I am trying to send GET request to a server that doesn't support URI encoding and the problem is that when I add cookie to the request header that has URL as it's value Ktor automatically encodes the cookie value in URI encoding style (replacing : and /).
How can I force Ktor to send the header raw? Without any encoding?
Appreciate any help :)
I add cookie to request header like:
header(HttpHeaders.Cookie, "session=https://test.com")
and the server receives the cookie like:
session=https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com

There is a way to send an already encoded cookie, preventing Ktor from encoding it the second time. Unfortunately, it's impossible to send the raw value containing special symbols.

But when I create separate implementation for iOS and Android using URLSession and OkHttpClient it doesn't add any encoding and sends the request as is. There seems to be some extra layer inside Ktor adding encoding and it seems really silly that there is no option to disable it...

I believe it is not an issue of a client. I just used your example and sniffed the traffic with tcpdump. It is not encoded.

Can you share how you built your KTOR https client?  Some configuration options can affect url encoding elsewhere.
